# in Prometheus, how to ignore a label in a range-vector (rate())

Tags: promql

i'm using Prometheus. i am trying to get the rate of a counter, no matter which tenant is being processed by the server.
for the rate expression i am using:
rate(token_generator_http_request_count{bundle="abcd", kubernetes_name="name_abcd"}[1m]

this gives me a different value for each of my tenants.
now i want to get the overall rate.
i tried using:
rate(token_generator_http_request_count{bundle="abcd", kubernetes_name="name_abcd"}[1m] without (tenant)

i'm getting an error. it seems Prometheus doesn't let using "without" for a range-vector function.
is there a way to unify the rate (without creating a new metric which will not set a tenant label at all)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> this gives me a different value for each of my tenants. now i want to get the overall rate

To get the overall rate (aggregated rate for all combinations of token_generator_http_request_count) you need to wrap the expression with aggregation function. For example:

```
sum(rate(token_generator_http_request_count{bundle="abcd", kubernetes_name="name_abcd"}[1m])
```

This expression will return you exactly one result: the sum of all rates. See live example [here](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.expr=sum(rate(prometheus_http_requests_total%5B5m%5D))%20&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h).

The `without` function can be used only with other aggregation functions. For example:

```
    sum(rate(token_generator_http_request_count{bundle="abcd", kubernetes_name="name_abcd"}[1m]) without(tenant)
```

This expression may return multiple results, grouped by all label combinations except label `tenant`. See live example [here](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.expr=sum(rate(prometheus_http_requests_total%5B5m%5D))%20without(code)&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h).